# Firebase getDisplayName() retorna vazio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-database, realtime-database

Eu tenho o seguinte código que deve retornar os dados do usuário logado pelo Firebase, ele retorna o usuário sem problema algum, o ID e o Email, mas o valor do nome retorna vazio ou nulo. Como se estivesse cadastrado o usuário sem nome, mas no cadastro consta o nome do usuário normalmente. Alguém sabe pq? Eu já pesquisei e parece que tem algum bug com o getDisplayName do Firebase. Já obtiveram uma solução?

```
public static FirebaseUser getUsuarioAtual() {
        FirebaseAuth usuario = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        return usuario.getCurrentUser();
    }

    public static Usuario getDadosUsuarioLogado() {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = getUsuarioAtual();

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setId(firebaseUser.getUid());
        usuario.setEmail(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        usuario.setNome(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());

        return usuario;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após uma pesquisa eu descobri que esse era um bug em algumas versões do Firebase, veja [aqui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/409#issuecomment-261694842).  Ele foi introduzido na versão **9.8.0**, então se você usar a versão **9.6.1** ele não ocorre. Eu não sei dizer se o bug já foi corrigido, mas tente usar a [última versão disponível](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), que é a **16.0.4**.

Nessa página que citei acima alguns usuários relataram problemas também com o método `FirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()`, além do método `FirebaseUser.getDisplayName()`.

Encontrei algumas soluções alternativas em respostas do SOen, veja se alguma resolve o seu problema.

Usando `FirebaseUser.getProviderData()` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38685639/8133067)):

```java
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String displayName = user.getDisplayName();
    Uri profileUri = user.getPhotoUrl();

    for (UserInfo userInfo : user.getProviderData()) {
        if (displayName == null && userInfo.getDisplayName() != null) {
            displayName = userInfo.getDisplayName();
        }
        if (profileUri == null && userInfo.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            profileUri = userInfo.getPhotoUrl();
        }
    }

    accountNameTextView.setText(displayName);
    if (profileUri != null) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(profileUri)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(userProfilePicture);
    }
}
```

Deslogando e [logando](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) novamente ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41417710/8133067)):

```java
// Comando para deslogar o usuário atual.
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
// Depois disso logar novamente:
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth
```

E outra pergunta sobre o mesmo assunto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50037129/8133067).

Comment: C.Oli, alguma solução funcionou para você? Deixe comentado aqui se sim ou se não, por favor, para ajudar outros que encontrem esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver excluindo os perfis já criados e criando novamente, ele passou a retornar normalmente o valor do nome. Com o método de deslogar e logar novamente tbm funciona.

Comment: Usando `FirebaseUser.getProviderData()` não funcionou pra mim